# I want to subtract 8 hours from current time. If I try to subtract 8 from hours, it goes in negative

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am using UTC time and want to subtract 8 hours from the current time. I am using JavaScript.

function getUTCStartDate(time) {

```
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = (d.getUTCMonth() + 1);
    var date = d.getUTCDate();
    var hours = d.getUTCHours();
    var hoursMinusTime = (d.getUTCHours() - time);
    var minutes = d.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds = d.getUTCSeconds();
    var millisec = d.getUTCMilliseconds();

    date = date.toString().length > 1 ? date : '0' + date;
    month = month.toString().length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
    hoursMinusTime = hoursMinusTime.toString().length > 1 ? hoursMinusTime : '0' + hoursMinusTime;
    minutes = minutes.toString().length > 1 ? minutes : '0' + minutes;
    seconds = seconds.toString().length > 1 ? seconds : '0' + seconds;
    millisec = millisec.toString().length > 1 ? millisec : '0' + millisec;


    return year + "-" + month + "-" + date + "T" + hoursMinusTime + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + millisec + "Z";
}
```

Comment: I guess this very much depends on your language; or more specifically: on the implementation of that Date class. Basically, it is impossible to provide a reasonable answer on such a question. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: @GhostCat I have added some more code and description.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in a different way. Converted the time in unix time deducted 8  hours from it.

```
var currTime = new Date();
var d = new Date(currTime.getTime() - (time * 3600000));
var hours = d.getUTCHours();
```